# What is the cheapest way to compute md5 digest in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, md5

I find there is `Data.Hash.MD5`, `Data.Digest.Pure.MD5` and a few [other](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=md5) md5sum libraries in Haskell. What is recommended/fastest if I only want to compute the `md5sum` of a `String`? I want to compute md5sum many many times, so I am looking for a cheap one.

Edit me if you find it not clear.

Comment: NB Unless you're interacting with a legacy system, there's probably no reason to MD5, and -- depending on what exactly you're doing -- good reasons not to use it.

Comment: Not sure what the fastest package is but I've found `cryptohash` to be fast enough and it covers a decent number of hashes http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptohash

Comment: This is a very open ended question.  What have you tried?  Have you benchmarked any of those libraries with optimizations turned on?

Comment: @bheklilr No, I am asking experts about their experience.

Answer (score 7):

Author of PureMD5 (`Data.Digest.Pure.MD5`) here.

"PureMD5" is pure in that it is written in pure Haskell, originally as an exercise while learning Haskell.  "Cryptohash" (`Data.Hash.MD5`) is a binding to a C implementation.  I haven't benchmarked against cryptohash specifically, but back in the day puremd5 was about 2-3 times slower than a straight-forward C implementation of MD5.